# Edit NSString with Page Breaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring

I am using a UITableView to display some data in my iOS app. The problem is, the `cell.textLabel.text` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text` is variable. For example, a phone number cell could be "Phone1" or it could be "Toll Free in the USA or Canada". In the second case, I would like to edit the string to be something like "Toll Free in\nthe USA or Canada". So I need some kind of method that will take a string, determine if it needs to be cut or not, then cuts it if it does.

Here's what I have so far:

```
NSString *stringToCut;  // This would be inputted
NSString *newString;    // This is the resultant string
int maxLength = 15;     // The maximum length.

if ([stringToCut length] > maxLength)
{
    //This is the problem: How do I find a space (" ") near the middle?
    int half = [stringToCut length]/2;
    int locationOfSpaceNearHalf = ???
    newString = [stringToCut subStringFromIndex:locationOfSpaceNearHalf];
    newString = [newString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n"];
    newString = [newstring stringByAppendingString:[stringToCut subStringFromIndex:locationofSpaceNearHalf+1]];
}
else 
{
    newString = stringToCut;
}

return newString;
```

The only thing I can think of would be to do a loop to generate the locations of all the spaces, then find the one that's nearest the halfway.

### Update

Here's two pictures, the first is what it would look like if we didn't do any formatting to the text. The second is what it would like if there were formatting.

[image: bad]
[image: good]

Or is there a better way to format the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it you're trying to achieve? Isn't the default UILabel behaviour good enough? 
Not sure if it helps, but you can get the size of the complete string as it would be rendered by calling `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` on `NSString`, and use that to see if the string will fit or not...

If that's not what you mean, please explain :)

Comment: I'm not using UILabels, I'm using cells in a UITableView. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?